# How to execute this javascript function from command line?

Tags: javascript, web, macros, imacros

I'm building a web macro and and I'm stuck at this point. This select shows a certain number of records per page (10, 20, 30, etc,100)

It fires this ajax code on change of the select element to bring back the number of records from that the select indicates.

I want to return 1500 results even though "1500" is not a select value.

My queestion is: How can I execute javascript to bring 1500 reords?

I will execute it on the address bar "Javascript:...."

Thanks

```
<select class="x2-minimal-select" onchange="$.ajax ({
                    data: {
                        results: $(this).val ()
                    },
                    url: &quot;/x2crm/index.php/profile/setResultsPerPage&quot;,
                    complete: function (response) {
                        $.fn.yiiGridView.update(&quot;contacts-grid&quot;, {data: {Contacts_page: 1},complete: function () {}});
                    }
                });" name="resultsPerPage" id="resultsPerPage">
<option value="10">10 rows</option>
<option value="20">20 rows</option>
 <option value="30">30 rows</option>
<option value="40">40 rows</option>
<option value="50">50 rows</option>
<option value="75">75 rows</option>
<option value="100" selected="selected">100 rows</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try to change the lines containing ‘data’ as follows:

```
    data: {
        results: '1500'
    },
```